# Get count with various conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I'm parsing an `SQL` command to a `mysqli` query. I would like to get the count of records with varying conditions. I currently do this with `union` but it is very slow. Is there a better more efficient way of doing this?

```
$sql  = "SELECT COUNT(*) as Total FROM table1 WHERE GroupId = 2 UNION ";
$sql .= "SELECT COUNT(*) as Likes FROM table1 WHERE LikesCol IS NOT NULL AND GroupId = 2 UNION ";
$sql .= "SELECT COUNT(*) as Commented FROM table1 WHERE CommentCol > 0 AND GroupId = 2 UNION ";
$sql .= "SELECT COUNT(*) as Shared FROM table1 WHERE SharedCol > 0 AND GroupId = 2";
```

As you will notice I am selecting all the records from the table where `GroupId = 2` then I am drilling down to who shared and commented etc.

Comment: Do you have an index on GroupId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(GroupId = 2) as Total,
       sum(LikesCol IS NOT NULL AND GroupId = 2) as Likes,
       sum(CommentCol > 0 AND GroupId = 2) as Commented,
       sum(SharedCol > 0 AND GroupId = 2) as Shared
FROM table1
```

and even better thanks to a hint of Paul

```
SELECT count(*) as Total,
       sum(LikesCol IS NOT NULL) as Likes,
       sum(CommentCol > 0) as Commented,
       sum(SharedCol > 0) as Shared
FROM table1
WHERE GroupId = 2
```